# How to add recent Wordpress posts to website that resides on separate domain

Tags: php, wordpress, rss

We have a client with two static HTML websites, each residing on separate domains. We have added a Wordpress blog to a sub directory of one of these sites and created a recent posts section to display on the main site using the code described here: [Adding recent Wordpress post, with featured image and excerpts to HTML site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43904954/adding-recent-wordpress-post-with-featured-image-and-excerpts-to-html-site)

We are trying to create a similar recent posts section on the site that resides on a separate domain. We would like to be able to style this section in a similar fashion.

There are many RSS feed services that allow us to import latest posts to a separate domain, but they are very limited in their styling options. We are looking for a custom solution that will allow us to produce a similar look.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display WordPress RSS feed your website?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9224280/how-to-display-wordpress-rss-feed-your-website)

Comment: Thanks @Picard. Not sure how I missed that. That answer is effective however, it does not include a thumbnail image from the post. Any idea what element tag name to use to pull the post thumbnail?